# Changing the height of a html button

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a button fit the height of it's parent, but I don't know how to do so.
I tried to figure out how the button in YouTube's navbar search worked, but even after removing all the styles the button had, it was still 100% of it's parent height.

Here's my code:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
    background: grey;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
    min-height: 50px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-items {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#nav-search {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background:black;
}

#search-button {

}

#search-input {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar" >
    <ul class="nav-items">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <span id="nav-search">
                <input id="search-input"></input>
                <button id="search-button">asdf</button>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: remove all align-items: center from parents and add height 100% to span in which input and button is wrapped, Thats all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add padding to your input elements.

```css
/* For Dark Color Scheme */
html {
  color-scheme: dark;
  scrollbar-color: #686868 #424242;
}

body {
  background: #272B3A;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  /*display: flex;*/
  /*justify-content: center;*/
}

/* * {
  font-size: 1rem;
} */
.container {
  margin: auto;
}

form {
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid #44E5FE;
}

input {
  /* appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none; */
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

input[type=submit] {
  padding: 0.7rem 1.3rem;
  border: 0;
}

input[type=text] {
  background: #272B3A;
  color: #FFF;
  border: 2px solid #414454;
  height: 32px;
}

.nav {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

input.submit {
  background: #FF5873;
  color: white;
}

button {
  background: #FF5873;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
/* My Additions Code Ends */

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  /* background: grey; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-items {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#nav-search {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* background:black; */
}

#search-button {
  padding: 10px;
}

#search-input {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar" >
    <ul class="nav-items">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <span id="nav-search">
                <input id="search-input"></input>
                <button id="search-button">button</button>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<p>Read the comment in the HTML code</p>
<!-- Just remember to add padding to your input elements. And <button> & <input type="button"> are the same thing -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `height` to your button

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

button {
  height: 50px;
}

.navbar {
  background: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-items {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#nav-search {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: black;
}

#search-button {}

#search-input {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="nav-items">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <span id="nav-search">
        <input id="search-input" />
        <button id="search-button">asdf</button>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass class to your button

CSS:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
    background: grey;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
    min-height: 50px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-items {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#nav-search {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background:black;
}

.search-button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

#search-input {
    height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar" >
    <ul class="nav-items">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <span id="nav-search">
                <input id="search-input"></input>
                <button id="search-button" class="search-button">asdf</button>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

As By your question you are trying to make the button the height of the `navbar` by putting `height: 100%` in `search-button` but the parent of the `search-button` is `nav-search` and its parent is `nav-items` and so on, hence the height of each element should be assigned a height of 100% or go with a particular height for `search-button`

```css
.navbar {
    background: grey;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.nav-items {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav-item {
    height:100%;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#nav-search {
    background:black;
    height: 100%;
}

#search-button {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar" >
    <ul class="nav-items">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <span id="nav-search">
                <input id="search-input"></input>
                <button id="search-button">asdf</button>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```